# Can a function be passed as an argument in PHP?

Tags: php, function, arguments

I am wanting to pass a functon as an argument using PHP, in the equivalent way that jQuery allows passing of functions.

jQuery:

```
$("#foo").bind("click", function(){

    alert("Hello world!");
});
```

So, I tried this using PHP:

```
$arg1 = "Hello";
$arg2 = function($name){echo $name;};

function call_me($func_arg1="", $func_arg2=""){

    echo $func_arg1." ".$func_arg2("world!");
}

call_me($arg1, $arg2);
```

... but I get "world!Hello" returned .... why does it return the outcome backwards ?

Answer (score 3):

ok, I found the answer. It was because I was trying to echo an echo! I changed it so that:

```
$arg2 = function($name){return $name;};
```

This output "Hello world!" as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
$arg2 = function($name){return $name;};
```

Comment: Code without an explanation is typically not very useful safe for a few cases. Please consider adding it.